# How can I compute the maximum in a vectorized lambda with NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to plot the maximum over two functions like this:

```py
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(-10, 100)
plt.plot(x, (lambda x: max(x**2, -.5 * x + 3))(x))
plt.show()
```

However, it complains about `max`:

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.

and also `np.max`:

> TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `lambda` function isn't operating on each element of the numpy array individually. It is operating on the *entire* array and `max` does not know how to compare two arrays. `np.max` also doesn't work because the second input should be the axis along which to compute the maximum and *not* an array.

You want to use [`np.maximum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) to compare corresponding elements in multiple arrays of the same size. It will yield the largest element at each location.

As an example

```
x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = np.array([3,2,1])

np.maximum(x, y)
#   3   2   3
```

And for your specific use-case:

```
plt.plot(x, np.maximum(x ** 2, -.5 * x + 3))
```

Comment: It's not calling `ndarray.max`; it's calling the regular `max` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this line instead:

```
np.array([x**2, 3-x/2]).max(0)
```

All together:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(-10, 100)
plt.plot(x, np.array([x**2, 3-x/2]).max(0))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand perfectly what you want with the last x-term in this line:

```
plt.plot(x, (lambda x: max(x**2, -.5 * x + 3))(x))
```

Anyway, you should be able to do something like this:

```
y_func = np.vectorize(lambda x: max(x**2, -.5 * x + 3))
plt.plot(x, y_func(y))
```